# Values not getting Stored in Linked List in Addition of Sparse matrix C Program

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I'm Trying to Add 2 sparse matrix using linked list.
I'm accepting values for 2 matrixes
Adding them and Storing them into a third matrix.
but for some reason the values are not getting stored in linked list, there is some memory issue.

I tried checking the conditions for adding node at end in a linked list.

```
//Suyash Ekhande's Approach to Sparse matrix Addition and Substraction.
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct SparseMatrix
{
    int row;
    int col;
    int val;
    struct SparseMatrix *next;
};
struct SparseMatrix *m1;
struct SparseMatrix *m2;
struct SparseMatrix *m3;

void printM1M2()
{
    struct SparseMatrix *mm1,*mm2;
    mm1=m1;
    mm2=m2;

    printf("Matrix1: \n");
    while(mm1->next!=NULL)
    {
        printf("Row: %d\tCol: %d\tVal: %d\n",mm1->row,mm1->col,mm1->val);
        mm1=mm1->next;
    }
    printf("Matrix2: \n");
    while(mm1->next!=NULL)
    {
        printf("Row: %d\tCol: %d\tVal: %d\n",mm2->row,mm2->col,mm2->val);
        mm2=mm2->next;
    }
}

void addMat1Values()
{
    struct SparseMatrix *ptr,*tmp;
    int row,col,val;
    ptr = (struct SparseMatrix*)malloc(sizeof(struct SparseMatrix));

    if(m1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nEnter Row Column and Value\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d",&row, &col, &val);
        ptr->row=row;
        ptr->col=col;
        ptr->val=val;
        ptr->next = NULL;
        m1 = ptr;

        printf("\n1st Node inserted");
    }
    else
    {
        tmp=m1;
        printf("\nEnter Row Column and Value\n");
            scanf("%d %d %d",&row, &col, &val);
        while(tmp->next!=NULL)
        {
            tmp=tmp->next;

        }
            ptr->row=row;
            ptr->col=col;
            ptr->val=val;
            tmp->next=ptr;
            ptr->next=NULL;

    printf("\nNode inserted");
    }
}

void addMat2Values()
{
    struct SparseMatrix *ptr,*tmp;
    int row,col,val;
    ptr = (struct SparseMatrix*)malloc(sizeof(struct SparseMatrix));
    if(m2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nEnter Row Column and Value\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d",&row, &col, &val);
        ptr->row=row;
        ptr->col=col;
        ptr->val=val;
        ptr->next = NULL;
        m1 = ptr;

    }
    else
    {
        tmp=m1;
        while(tmp->next!=NULL)
        {
            tmp=tmp->next;

        }

        printf("\nEnter Row Column and Value\n");
            scanf("%d %d %d",&row, &col, &val);
            ptr->row=row;
            ptr->col=col;
            ptr->val=val;
            tmp->next=ptr;
            ptr->next=NULL;
    printf("\nNode inserted");
    }
}
void copyElement(int r,int c,int v)
{
    struct SparseMatrix *ptr,*temp;
    ptr = (struct SparseMatrix*)malloc(sizeof(struct SparseMatrix));

    ptr->row=r;
    ptr->col=c;
    ptr->val=v;
    if(m3 == NULL)
    {
        ptr -> next = NULL;
        m3 = ptr;
        printf("\nNode inserted");
    }
    else
    {
        temp = m3;
        while (temp -> next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp -> next;
        }
        temp->next = ptr;
        ptr->next = NULL;
        printf("\nNode inserted");

    }
    }



void addTheMatrixFinally()
{
    struct SparseMatrix *mat1;
    struct SparseMatrix *mat2;
    mat1=m1;
    mat2=m2;

    if(mat1 == NULL || mat2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Matrices are Null!!");
    }
    while(mat1 !=NULL && mat2!=NULL)
    {
        if(mat1->row == mat2->row && mat1->col == mat2->col)
        {
            int row,col,val;
            row=mat1->row;
            col=mat1->col;
            val=mat1->val + mat2->val;
            copyElement(row,col,val);
              mat1=mat1->next;
            mat2=mat2->next;
        }
        else if(mat1->row < mat2->row || mat1->col < mat2->col)
        {//mat 1 ele is smaller
         //copy the element to final matrix
         copyElement(mat1->row,mat1->col,mat1->val);
         mat1=mat1->next;
         //go to next element
        }
        else if(mat1->row > mat2->row || mat1->col > mat2->col)
        {//mat 2 ele is smaller
            //copy the element to final matrix
         copyElement(mat1->row,mat1->col,mat1->val);
         mat2=mat2->next;
         //go to next element
        }

    }
}

void printSparseMatrix()
{
    int r,c,v;
    struct SparseMatrix *mat;
    mat = m3;

    if(mat == NULL)
    {
    printf("\n result matrice are null");
    }
    else
    {
        while(mat->next!=NULL)
        {
            r=mat->row;
            c=mat->col;
            v=mat->val;
            printf("Row: %d\tCol: %d\tVal: %d",r,c,v);
            mat=mat->next;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int l,i, j;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter Number of Elements: ");
    scanf("%d",&l);
    printf("Enter Matrix 1 Elements");
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        addMat1Values();
    }
    printf("\nEnter Matrix 2 Elements");
    for(j=0;j<l;j++)
    {
        addMat2Values();    
    }
    printM1M2();
    addTheMatrixFinally();
    printSparseMatrix();

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The Expected output should be the 3rd Matrix shown in the form of linked list.
But the Output prompts the Matrix 1 and 2 to be Null which is checked by an Condition.

Answer (score 1):

In your `addMat2value` function which is supposed to add entries to `m2` list is instead adding entries to `m1` list.

```
void addMat2Values()
{
    struct SparseMatrix *ptr,*tmp;
    int row,col,val;
    ptr = (struct SparseMatrix*)malloc(sizeof(struct SparseMatrix));
    if(m2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nEnter Row Column and Value\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d",&row, &col, &val);
        ptr->row=row;
        ptr->col=col;
        ptr->val=val;
        ptr->next = NULL;
        m1 = ptr;

    }
    else
    {
        tmp=m1;
        while(tmp->next!=NULL)
        {
            tmp=tmp->next;

        }

        printf("\nEnter Row Column and Value\n");
            scanf("%d %d %d",&row, &col, &val);
            ptr->row=row;
            ptr->col=col;
            ptr->val=val;
            tmp->next=ptr;
            ptr->next=NULL;
    printf("\nNode inserted");
    }
}
```

should be

```
void addMat2Values()
{
    struct SparseMatrix *ptr,*tmp;
    int row,col,val;
    ptr = (struct SparseMatrix*)malloc(sizeof(struct SparseMatrix));
    if(m2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nEnter Row Column and Value\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d",&row, &col, &val);
        ptr->row=row;
        ptr->col=col;
        ptr->val=val;
        ptr->next = NULL;
        m2 = ptr;

    }
    else
    {
        tmp=m2;
        while(tmp->next!=NULL)
        {
            tmp=tmp->next;

        }

        printf("\nEnter Row Column and Value\n");
            scanf("%d %d %d",&row, &col, &val);
            ptr->row=row;
            ptr->col=col;
            ptr->val=val;
            tmp->next=ptr;
            ptr->next=NULL;
    printf("\nNode inserted");
    }
}
```

> Aside :: Although You could have just defined the single function and
>   passed `m1` or `m2` list as argument to it.

Comment: I made Correction @kiran Biradar but i still get Null in linked list

Comment: @technogeek Please correct all of your typos for example you are cheking `mm1->next!=NULL` condition while printing `m2` in `printM1M2` function.

Comment: I had done m1=mm1; so that doesnt affect anything. There arent any typos. @kiran Biradar

Comment: @technogeek: The way you code is very prone to be affected by typos, of which you make quite a lot. Don't be stubborn when these obvious mistakes are pointed out to you. Here's another one: In `addTheMatrixFinally` you don't advance `mat1` and `mat2` in the case where they have the same indices, which results in an infinite loop. And if you require that the nodes are sorted when you traverse them, you should enforce that each list is sorted when you insert new nodes.

Comment: Your sparse matrix is just a linked list and you should only have a few unique functions to create, delete, print and add a list, where the matrix in question is passed as argument. Please look a bit more into how functions work.

Comment: @MOehm I made changes as you said. Still getting Null Matrices

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of errors, both conceptional flaws and actual syntax errors.

- What you call a sparse matrix is not really a matrix, it's just a linked list of (row, col, value) items without duplicates. A real matrix needs information about its number of rows and columns. How are you going to find cells efficiently? How are you going to multiply matrices? As s, the coe is only useful for addition and subtraction.
- The most glaring fault is that your functions operate on the three global variables `m1`, `m2` and ´m3`. You then write functions that are specialized to these values. Your functions should take the matrices as arguments. There's no need to write three functions for printing that basically do the same thing, only for diferent matrices. (This kind of copy-and-past programming also gives ample oppurtunity for typos, as your code shows.)
- When you add matrices, you rely on a certain ordering, but (1) you don't enforce that ordering when you construct the matrices and (2) the way you enfoerce the ordering does not work, because it is not unique: The conditions `r1 < r2 || c1 < c2` and `r1 > r2 || c1 > c2`  are not mutually exclusive.
- When you insert the node at the end, you must iterate over the list with `while (m->next) ...`, because you want to get the last node. When you oprint the list, you should use `while (m) ...`, otherwise you will skip the last node.
- In general, your control flow has too much duplicated code. There's no need to place the code for reading into each of the branches of an `if`, foe example. This should be common code. Ideally, the code for reading and for inserting a node should be separate.

The following trivial fixes will make your code print the result matrix. That matrix may not be correct, though, because the ordering problem isn't fixed here:

```
In printM1M2, line 6:           while(mm1!=NULL)        // was: mm1->next
In printM1M2, line 12:          while(mm2!=NULL)        // was: mm2->next

In addMat2Values, line 12:      m2 = ptr;               // was: m1 = ptr
In addMat2Values, line 17:      tmp=m2;                 // was: tmp=m1
```

Below is an implementation that works. It uses three local variables in `main` for the matrices, it inserts the nodes in a certain order and uses that order when adding the matrices. It also frees the linked lists after use. (I'm not going to explain much here, please look at other answers here for details.)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct Sparse Sparse;

struct Sparse {
    int row;
    int col;
    int val;
    Sparse *next;
};

/*
 *      Nodes that are "less" than others come first in the list.
 */
bool sp_less(const Sparse *a, const Sparse *b)
{
    if (a->row < b->row) return true;
    if (a->row > b->row) return false;
    return (a->col < b->col);
}

/*
 *      Add a value to the matrix at row, col.
 */
void sp_set(Sparse **sp, int row, int col, int val)
{
    Sparse *sn = malloc(sizeof(*sn));

    sn->row = row;
    sn->col = col;
    sn->val = val;
    sn->next = NULL;

    while (*sp && sp_less(*sp, sn )) {
        sp = &(*sp)->next;
    }

    if (*sp == NULL || sp_less(sn, *sp)) {
        sn->next = *sp;
        *sp = sn;
    } else {
        (*sp)->val += val;
        free(sn);
    }
}

/*
 *      Print the non-null elements of a matrix
 */
void sp_print(const Sparse *sp, const char *name)
{
    while (sp) {
        printf("%s(%d, %d) == %d\n",
            name, sp->col, sp->row, sp->val);
        sp = sp->next;
    }

    puts("");
}

/*
 *      Destroy a matrix and free the memory.
 */
void sp_destroy(Sparse *sp)
{
    while (sp) {
        Sparse *next = sp->next;

        free(sp);
        sp = next;
    }
}

/*
 *      Add two matrices and return the new matrix
 */
Sparse *sp_add(const Sparse *a, const Sparse *b)
{
    Sparse *res = NULL;

    while (a && b) {
        if (sp_less(a, b)) {
            sp_set(&res, a->row, a->col, a->val);
            a = a->next;
        } else if (sp_less(b, a)) {
            sp_set(&res, b->row, b->col, b->val);
            b = b->next;
        } else {
            sp_set(&res, b->row, b->col, a->val + b->val);
            a = a->next;
            b = b->next;
        }
    }

    while (a) {
        sp_set(&res, a->row, a->col, a->val);
        a = a->next;
    }

    while (b) {
        sp_set(&res, b->row, b->col, b->val);
        b = b->next;
    }

    return res;
}

/*
 *      Hard-coded example.
 */
int main(void)
{
    Sparse *a = NULL;
    Sparse *b = NULL;
    Sparse *res = NULL;

    sp_set(&a, 0, 0, 1);
    sp_set(&a, 1, 1, 1);
    sp_set(&a, 2, 2, 1);
    sp_print(a, "a");

    sp_set(&b, 2, 0, 1);
    sp_set(&b, 1, 1, 1);
    sp_set(&b, 0, 2, 1);
    sp_print(b, "b");

    res = sp_add(a, b);
    sp_print(res, "res");

    sp_destroy(a);
    sp_destroy(b);
    sp_destroy(res);

    return 0;
}
```